# Combining two Columns

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an SQL table with 4 columns. The fourth column is FullName. I want this column to autofill itself from the results of 2nd and 3rd Column. ie.Firstname and Middlename.

I have tried this code

```
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName ) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & " ', CONCATE(Textbox2.text, ',', Textbox3.Text))"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Comment: a) Throw that away and use SQL parameters; that code will fail on a great many names and is vulnerable to SQL injection, b) depending on the DB (which you did not mention) it is probably not `CONCATE` but `CONCAT` - you will have to check the syntax as it can vary.

Comment: Did you intend for the Fullname to have the Firstname and Middlename be separated by a comma or the more traditional space.  Example: is "Henry,Gathigira" or "Henry Gathigira" the correct Fullname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section CONCATINATE will be like the following:

```
"CONCATE('" & Textbox2.text &"',',','" & Textbox3.Text & "'))"
```

But i wont tell you to use like this, since it may a worst suggestion. I prefer you to use parameters as well to avoid injection and specifying the types.

Example:

```
Dim query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName ) VALUES (" & _
            "@adm,@fName,@mName,CONCATE(@fNameC,',',@mNameC))"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@adm", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fNameC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mNameC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
'Execute the query here
```

Answer (score 0):

Before query first store two textbox value in one variable

```
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
Dim fullname As String 
fullname = TextBox1.text + "" + TextBox2.text
query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName ) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & " ', '" & fullname & '")"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Comment: How you planning to  handle the injection

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate with `String.Concat`, and I advice you to use the `Parameter` to avoid sql injections, like this :

```
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName ) VALUES (@Adm,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@FullName)"
cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Adm", TextBox1.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MiddleName", TextBox3.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FullName", String.Concat(TextBox2.Text, ",", TextBox3.Text)))
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the Firstname and Middlename values into variables and `concat()` them together before sending to the query.

```
cn.Open()
Dim query As String
Dim firstname As String
Dim middlename As String
Dim fullname As String
query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName) VALUES (@Adm,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@FullName)"

firstname = TextBox2.Text
middlename = TextBox3.Text
fullname = String.Concat(firstname, ",", middlename)

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Adm", TextBox1.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FirstName", firstname))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MiddleName",middlename))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FullName", fullname))
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
```

Note that the query builder has been reformatted to remove vulnerability to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use following line instead of your.

```
query = "Insert into Details(Adm,FirstName,MiddleName,FullName ) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & " ', '" & Textbox2.Text & " " & Textbox3.Text & "')"
```